# how to create thumbnail icon using geoServer on openlayer

Tags: javascript, geoserver

how to use geoServer to generate the map thumbnail icon automatically?

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer will produce an image of your map if you ask for using a `GetMap` request. So you could easily come up with a script that requested your `getCapabilities` document and then for each layer in that calculated a suitable width and height based on the aspect ratio of the bounding box of the layer and then plugged those values into a `getMap` request and fire off the request and save the response as an image.

You could then place them in GeoServer's `www` directory (inside your data directory) where they will be published as `http://...../geoserver/www/image.png`.